# Integral in dimension 7

Tags: integration, geometry, inequality, approximation

I want to compute the volume of region bounded by the inequalities : $x_2x_4x_6\geq x_1x_3x_5x_7, x_1x_4x_5\geq x_2x_3x_6x_7, x_3x_4x_7\geq x_1x_2x_5x_6, x_1x_2x_3\geq x_4x_5x_6x_7, x_2x_5x_7\geq x_1x_3x_4x_6, x_1x_6x_7\geq x_2x_3x_4x_5, x_3x_5x_6\geq x_1x_2x_4x_7, 0\leq x_i\leq 1.$

Is there any easy ways to compute this volume or a method to approximate the volume?

The easier version $x\geq yz,y\geq xz,z\geq xy,0<x,y,z\leq1$ can be solved by cutting the region defined by the inequality with the plane $z=a$ and then see what the plane section looks like.

Comment: I do see the structure in the inequalities (a 7-fold symmetry that could be turned into a cyclic permutation of coordinates with a suitable relabelling), but looks tough to calculate this exactly. If pressed for time I would do a Monte Carlo simulation here. Generate a zillion random 7-tuples, and check how often they satisfy the constraints.

Comment: On second thought, I might resort to Monte Carlo even if I were not pressed for time :-) Not ruling out the possibility that some smart person sees a way to handle this!

Comment: The structure I see is the following. After a relabelling of the variables the inequalities relate triple products $x_ix_{i+1}x_{i+3}$ to the complementary quadruple products. Here the index $i$ takes all the values from $1$ to $7$, and the sums of the subscripts are calculated modulo $7$. I haven't worked out the related relabelling, but one exists because the combinatorial design, where A) each variable occurs in exactly three triple products, and B) each variable occurs together with every other variable in a triple product exact once, is unique up to relabelling.

Comment: I asked Mathematica to approximately compute the volume using RegionMeasure of an ImplicitRegion using the NIntegrate method, but it gave up after about 25 minutes.  (It handled your easier version in a second.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it is indeed also the pattern that I see but still do not know what to do about it.

Comment: @KyleMiller Yes, Mathematica gave up too :(

Comment: I ran a quick Monte Carlo sim with Mathematica. Barring a bug this is what I'm seeing. Even though a random point in $[0,1]^7$ satisfies a *single one* of those constraint with probability roughly 65 percent, the probability of it satisfying all seven constraints is surprisingly low. Only  $1950$ vectors out of $10^6$ passed all seven tests. I don't have a strong intuition about this. I guess what's happening is that a single small coordinate will make one of the constraints fail more easily.

Comment: (cont'd) To satisfy my curiosity I also tested vectors for only six of the seven constraints, and that had a huge impact: ten times more vectors passed 6/7 tests. Anyway, this sim suggests that the 7-volume is only a bit less than $2/1000$. Obviously the sim needs to be redone by somebody else. I used the "cyclic" variant of constraints from a few comments up.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If the 7D version is anything like the 3D version (which I'd plotted) I'm not surprised by your findings.  The 3D version is like three triangles sharing the same edge, then puffed up by some hyperbolic parabolae draped between them; maybe analogously in 7D it is very close to being a 6D figure.  There's some symmetry about the $x_1=\cdots=x_7$ line. Maybe projecting along it gives a 6D figure with low area?